# How can I reduce a series of detailed time stamps with hours and minutes to just the date?

Tags: datetime, time, timestamp

I have a data table that records the date as year-month-day hour:minute:second as seen below.

```
2011-10-20 10:48:41, 2011-10-20 10:51:37, 2011-11-20 11:01:46 , 2011-11-20 11:16:03 ,2011-11-20 12:02:33
```

Each time stamp correlates to a specific item. I am trying to count the number of items per day but when I try and group by that date, it gives me a list of all of them because the time stamps are so specific. Is there a way to cut down the time stamp so that it will only look at 2011-10-20 vs 2011-10-20 10:48:41.

I tried several using a between function for either selecting the time stamp or in the grouping function but had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which programming language you are using, but there are tons of tools to parse date and time. For example, there's the `DateTime.Parse()` method for .NET framework.

If you do not want to use framework tools, you could always use `String.split()` on the date time strings and pass in a space as the delimiter, and then only keep the first element of the result array.

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL here is how you remove the timestamp from a datetime.
CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, [DateColumn])))

In .NET all datetime objects have a Date property that will give you the date portion without the timestamp. For example if you had a datetime object name myDate then myDate.Date would give you a new object with just the date part.

EDIT: After reading your question again I came to the conclusion you were trying to do this in SQL. I put you a quick example together.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS DailyItemCount, NewItemDate
FROM (  
    SELECT ItemId,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, ItemDate))) AS NewItemDate
    FROM MyTable
) AS NoTimeTable
GROUP BY NoTimeTable.NewItemDate
```